# How to make icecast relay the metadata of mp3 stream from ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, icecast

I'm trying to relay a internet radio stream with the command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'http://internetradiourl'-vn -acodec copy -f tee -map 0:a "[f=mp3]icecast://source:pass@icecast:8000/a|[f=mp3]icecast://source:pass@icecast:8000/b"
```

the output stream has all the metadata:

```
Output #0, tee, to '[f=mp3]icecast://source:pass@icecast:8000/a|[f=mp3]icecast://source:pass@icecast:8000/b':
  Metadata:
    audiocodec      : MP3
    audiodevice     : IN  1+2 (Digigram LoLa280)
    audiodeviceid   : e08a462b-2944-4abf-894a-5d5e8649452d
    type            : event
    encoderMachineName: ERADIO
    hasAudio        : true
    hasCuePoints    : true
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : false
    source          : MediaProxy 4.4.13.6
    name            : ad
    ad_type         : endbreak
    cue_id          : b6c7ff39-2103-4442-bdc8-35f8ba2bb97d
    cue_time_duration: 44.365
    cue_time_start  : 1610035039552
    cue_title       : PSA - Danny - Parking (Jun 2020)
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98304 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
```

but if a client connects to the icecast server, the metadata is lost:
`ffprobe https://icecasturl/a`

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'https://icecasturl/a':
  Metadata:
    icy-pub         : 0
    icy-metadata    : 1
    StreamTitle     :
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
```

How can I configure icecast so that it forwards all the metadata of the source stream?

Comment: for that ffmpeg would need to send the *out of band* metadata to icecast. It is likely that this is *not* supported by ffmpeg. Why do you think you need ffmpeg for this?

Comment: it's just happened that I'm using ffmpeg to do this, so no particular reason. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do other than using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider directly relaying using Icecast instead.

The relevant documentation is here: https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/relaying.html

There is no particular reason to use ffmpeg in this use case.

Comment: I can't get it to work. The source might not be icecast or shoutcast server. The source URL is `https://18323.live.streamtheworld.com:443/988_FM`, if you might want to test.

I have the following paragraph in `icecast.xml`:
```
<relay>
        <server>https://18323.live.streamtheworld.com</server>
        <port>443</port>
        <mount>/988_FM</mount>
        <local-mount>/988relay</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>1</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
```

Comment: this is the first time you mention TLS. Icecast in this form currently doesn't support relaying HTTPS. Though that server responds to HTTP, so just use port `80` instead.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work with relay. But it seem to be a bit spotty. I can't connect multiple client to the mount. So only one client can listen to the stream it a time despite `<max-listeners>` is set to 10 in <mount>

Comment: sounds like an unrelated problem. make sure that you are not hitting bandwidth limitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the metadata forwarded in band then your initial request must include the header:

```
Icy-MetaData: 1
```

The server will then insert the metadata into the stream. How you choose to parse it is up to you.